# What is the difference between two querysets and django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, difference

i have two querysets and i want to get the difference between them 
and pass them in one query to use it in my view and display to my template

```
for price_date in pkg.prices_dates.all():
    for territory in price_date.territory.all():
         territory
```

result:
United Kingdom
Belgium

```
for territory in pkg.territories.all():
    territory
```

result:
Belgium
Canada
France
United Kingdom

i want to get 
Canada
France

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    data.update({

        'territory_not_selected':#####
    })
```

Comment: Post the models. Which querysets? And define the meaning of the `difference between two querysets`.

Comment: Do you want to find territories without prices linked?

Comment: thank you i found the answer i did the union of two querysets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a diff for each pkg

```
all_territories = pkg.territories.all()
difference = {}
for price_date in pkg.prices_dates.all():
    current_territories = price_date.territory.all():
    difference[pkg.id] = list(set(all_territories) - set(current_territories))
```

the result will be the `difference` dictionary where each key is a `pkg` id with difference as a value.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i used the union of two querysets